# Override CSS Bottom-Border length

Tags: html, css

How can I set the bottom-border length of an element to be the full width of the page regardless of the size of its container?

At the moment, the bottom border is 200px off of the full width of the page (100px left & 100px right).

```
#portfolio {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#portfolio #item {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    border-bottom-color: #cdcdcd;   
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul id="portfolio">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#portfolio > li {
    padding: 30px 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/eFNXy/2/

When you have multiple items, then that represents a list and you use the UL element.

Comment: The border should show up in the #item element rather than the #portfolio element.

Comment: @max_ You mean, there are other elements after #item inside #portfolio?

Answer (score 0):

Change `#portfolio`'s margins to padding.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference, the border is still 200px off the full width.